# VS Code autocomplete for external libraries not working, JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I work on my React project on Visual Studio code and I installed via npm
Google Charts.
Now I want the VS Code to show me suggestions, but it does not work.
The same is with any other library like FontAwsome, axios and more.

What to do?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do these libraries have ```@types``` packages you need to install as well?

Comment: No...............